# Help me to find the centroid

Tags: integration

Find the centroid [image]  of the region bounded by: [image]

there is something wrong with my limits I am really lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

The formula for Centroid

$$\bar x =\dfrac{ \int_0^4 x(f(x)-g(x)) dx}{\int_0^4 (f(x)-g(x))dx}$$

$$f(x) = 5x^2+2x; g(x) = 0
$$
$$bar x =\dfrac{\int_0^4 x(5x^2+2x) dx}{\int_0^4 (5x^2+2x)dx}$$

Rest is simple and if you evaluate, it will come to $2.9566$

$$\bar y= \dfrac{ \int_0^4 \frac{(f(x)+g(x))}{2}(f(x)-g(x)) dx}{\int_0^4 (f(x)-g(x))dx}$$

$$\bar y= 26.45$$

Comment: what is your question? It will have the coordinate ($\bar x, \bar y$)

Comment: the x bar is correct but y bar is wrong, i tried to find out whats wrong with it but i couldn't!

Comment: Yeah now Its right, thanks i appreciate that!

Comment: Oops, I made an error in the calculation.  I have corrected it.  The integral is very simple and you can do it yourself.  Thanks

Comment: Could you accept the solution, Thanks