# Centroid of a triangle

Tags: integration

Find the centroid [image]
of the triangle with vertices at [image]
[image]
and  [image]

I am having troubles with finding the integral!

Comment: Are you sure of those coordinates? Two of the vertices are the same.

Comment: I guess you mean $(1,0),(0,1),(0,7)$.

Comment: actually it has to be (0,0)(1,0) and (0,7)

Comment: Have a look at the solution to the other question like this you asked recently: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706308/help-me-to-find-the-centroid

Can you use the help there to set up an integral? If so, what troubles are you having with it, exactly?

Comment: yeah that I tried to follow that but i am still confussed

Comment: Confused about what? Maybe you can update your question to include the integrals you have set up and the work you have done so far?

Comment: Without integrals, simply$$(\bar{x},\bar{y})=\left(\dfrac{1}{3},\dfrac{7}{3}\right)$$See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_triangle_and_tetrahedron

Comment: OK, so draw the triangle. What functions bound the region from above and below? What functions bound on the left and right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use integration. This triangle is clearly a right triangle with side lengths 1 and 7. The centroid is the intersection of the three medians. Therefore, the slope of one  median is the slope passing through the line (0, 7) and (0.5, 0) and the slope of another median is the slope of the line passing through (1, 0) and (0, 3.5).

Saving you a bit of time, these two slopes are -14 and -3.5, respectively. The y intercept of the first line is 7, so that line has an equation of $y = -14x + 7$, and the second line has an equation of $y = -3.5x + 3.5$. By solving these two equations in  a linear system of equations, you should arrive at your answer.

Hit me up if you need more help!